# How to configure filmstrip on mobile for custom Jitsi instance?

Tags: open-source, self-hosting, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am trying to configure my Jitsi meet so it will have filmstrip on mobile.

Please see ~/.jitsi-meet-cfg/web/custom-config.js below[image: jitsi config]

But for whatever film strip view won’t appear on mobile even though it shows on desktop. What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iframe was able to resolve it programmatically.

```
jitsiApi.addEventListener('filmstripDisplayChanged', (event: any) => {
                if (!event.visible) {
                    jitsiApi.executeCommand('toggleFilmStrip');
                }
            });
```